# Unprotect / take ownership on nodes in CQ

Tags: aem, day-cq

i have an big content package to import within CQ and some nodes are owned by users.
Every time when i try to import the package as admin, i get an error that the node is protected. So i have to impersonate as this user and remove the ownership to continue the import process.
Is there an easy way to take ownership / remove the protection as admin user for a whole tree?

Regards
Patrick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you install the package through the Package Manager [1] interface, you should be able to tell CQ how to handle access controls.  I think if you set the **AC Handling** option to Ignore, then the permissions that come with the package will not be applied.

[1] http://dev.day.com/docs/en/crx/current/how_to/package_manager.html#Using%20the%20Package%20Manager

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, already tried this. Problem could be solved otherwise. Fresh instance + ACL Export + Contentexport via Packager Manager (not Content Zipper).